# fatal error: yaml-cpp/yaml.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, yaml-cpp

I am trying to compile my own c++/qt5.2 app which uses yaml-cpp under Ubuntu 14.04.

While issuing the `make` command I get the following error

```
fatal error: yaml-cpp/yaml.h: No such file or directory
```

on the line:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @NathanielJohnson qt 5.2 itself does not require yaml, but the program I was trying to compile requires yaml. I edited my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to **install the yaml-cpp library**.

Under Ubuntu 14.04 you can do this by simply running one of the following commands in a terminal window (depending one the API you use):

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-cpp-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-cpp0.3-dev
```

See the [yaml-cpp project page](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/) for other operating systems and differences between old (0.3) and new API.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS:

```
sudo yum install libyaml-devel libyaml yaml-cpp-devel
```

Comment: This is correct...it lacks meat under NORMAL guidelines for here- but fortunately, you're adding an addendum to the answer as an answer...